# In flutter web, when using PdfPreview from the printing package, getting setting exports error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

When using Flutter version 3.10.0, I am getting the following error when using PdfPreview() from the printing package:

> `TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'exports') https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.2.146/build/pdf.min.js 22:113  webpackUniversalModuleDefinition https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.2.146/build/pdf.min.js 22:294  <fn> Error: NoSuchMethodError: '[]' Dynamic call of null. Receiver: null Arguments: ["GlobalWorkerOptions"] dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:49      throw_ dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 813:3   defaultNoSuchMethod dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 807:56  noSuchMethod dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 283:12  callNSM dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 294:25  _checkAndCall dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 431:10  callMethod dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 435:5   dsend packages/printing/printing_web.dart 90:29                                         _initPlugin dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                <fn> dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 784:44                                        handleValueCallback dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 813:13                                        _propagateToListeners dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 575:7                                         [_complete] dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1581:7                                             <fn> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 367:37  _checkAndCall dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 372:39  dcall dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37263:58                              <fn>`

I downgraded to Flutter version 3.7.12, compiled again, and it worked fine. Repeated the process and kept getting same result (working with 3.7.12, not working with 3.10.0). Does someone know if a dependency has to be added or changed? As I understand it might be an error when compiling to JavaScript on the exports section.

Answer (score 1):

Paste the below lines of code in pubspec.yml

dependency_overrides:
pdf:
git:
url: https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf
ref: master
path: pdf
printing:
git:
url: https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf
ref: master
path: printing

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works correctly! Any clue when this override will no longer be necessary anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer yet, but I am experiencing the exact same problem. Everything functions well on Android, iOS, and MacOS; then fails when I run it for the web...

If I find a solution I will post it here.